# float4 missaligned access ? debug works, release dont

Tags: visual-studio-2008, cuda

Environment: Cuda 5.0, GTX 480, windows 7 x64, VS2008

Ok, first, let me know if this is legal:

```
//this code isnt actually the real code I have on my app
do_something(float *vector) {

   float4 myvar = *(float4*)&vector[threadIdx.x]; //missalignment issues??

}
```

I have somewhat complex kernel and on similar code I get strange behavior. Each thread has to fetch 4 consecutive floats and I thought fetching them all on a single transaction would be better. So I tried to access them as a single float4 ...

Compiler doesnt complain, memchecker doesnt get any wrong either. Running it on debug mode seems to work (not sure, cant test the results). But on release mode it gives an "unknown error". It seems that if I try to access a float4 I have to do it aligned to 128B, is this correct? if it is, why memchecker doesn't complain? Why it does work on debug and doesnt on release??

BTW if I perform 4 transactions for doing the operation (one float at time), it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the CUDA C Programming Guide on [Global Size and Alignment Requirements](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses)

> Global memory instructions support reading or writing words of size
>   equal to 1, 2, 4, 8, or 16 bytes. Any access (via a variable or a
>   pointer) to data residing in global memory compiles to a single global
>   memory instruction if and only if the size of the data type is 1, 2,
>   4, 8, or 16 bytes and the data is naturally aligned (i.e., its address
>   is a multiple of that size).

The natural alignment for float4 is 128-bits so your accesses have to be aligned to 128-bits.

Compute capability 2.0 and above devices with throw hardware exceptions on misaligned accesses. Compute capability 1.* devices will return incorrect results.

Comment: thanks Greg. So, why my code is actually executed in DEBUG mode and not in RELEASE? is there any explanation?

Comment: debug mode (-G) affects compiler code generation.  It's possible that the compiler is generating different code (different access sequence) for this line of source code with or without the -G switch.  You can compare the PTX code in each case (nvcc -ptx ...) to see if this is the case.

Comment: It's also possible that your float array just happens to fall on an address that is a multiple of four words and thus suitably aligned for float4 access, and in that case your code just happens to work. The chance of that is 25%.

Comment: @njuffa Given the expression &vector[threadIdx.x] the program would have to meet the following condition: (blockDim.x == 1 && (&vector[0] & 0xF == 0))

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you are trying to say. My point is, on the GPU all data must be naturally aligned. Casting a pointer to data of one type (e.g. float, 4-byte alignment) into a pointer of a type with tighter required alignment (e.g. float4, 16-byte alignment) will thus not in general result in a pointer with proper alignment, and thus the OP's code is broken. However, in some cases an N-byte aligned pointer happens to also be N*4-byte aligned, and then the code happens to work. The chance is 1/4 for a purely random case, but for example is 1 if the pointer comes straight from cudaMalloc().

Comment: well i'm sure my code will result in non-aligned to 16B both in debug and release (it explores all possible offsets). Maybe the debug mode is generating 4 loads instead of one? I'll check both ptx codes